# $ Projection query from mongodb to mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want want to replicate this query in mongoose.

```
db.collection.find( { <array>: <value> ... }, { "<array>.$": 1 } )
```

Doing the same query in mongoose does not work. Also I can't find a documentation about it and also I can't think of a query in mongoose to have the same effect or result.

Example in mongodb [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#examples)

Comment: You need to provide more information here. Post your exact code, show you schema, or anything which may help to understand the problem.

Comment: Just like this example [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#examples).